# Pass a fortran derived type which contains allocatable array between different compilers(PGI and Intel)

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, intel, pgi

We have a project which evolves Nvidia GPU and Intel Xeon Phi. The host code and the GPU code is written in Fortran and compiled by pgfortran. To offload some of our job to the Phi, we have to make a shared library compiled by the ifort( static link cannot work) and call the shared subroutine from the pgfortran part of the code. By doing so, we can offload arrays from the pgfortran part of code to the intel fortran shared library which can communicate with the Xeon Phi.

Now I'm trying to pass a derived type which contains allocatable arrays from the pgfortran part of code to the ifort shared library. Looks like there are some problems.

Here is a simple example( no Xeon Phi offload directive here):

caller.f90:

```
program caller                                                                           

type cell                                                                                
integer :: id                                                                            
real, allocatable :: a(:)                                                                
real, allocatable :: b(:)                                                                
real, allocatable :: c(:)                                                                
end type cell                                                                            

integer :: n,i,j

type(cell) :: cl(2)                                                                      
 n=10                                                                                    
do i=1,2                                                                                 
allocate(cl(i)%a(n))                                                                     
allocate(cl(i)%b(n))                                                                     
allocate(cl(i)%c(n))                                                                     
end do                                                                                   


do j=1, 2                                                                                
do i=1, n                                                                                
cl(j)%a(i)=10*j+i                                                                        
cl(j)%b(i)=10*i+j                                                                        
end do                                                                                   
end do                                                                                   


call offload(cl(1))                                                                      
print *, cl(1)%c  
end program caller
```

called.f90:

```
subroutine  offload(cl)                                                                  
type cell                                                                                
integer :: id                                                                            
real, allocatable :: a(:)                                                                
real, allocatable :: b(:)                                                                
real, allocatable :: c(:)                                                                
end type cell

type(cell) :: cl                                                                         
integer :: n

print *, cl%a(1:10)
print *, cl%b(1:10)   
end subroutine offload
```

Makefile:

```
run: caller.o libcalled.so
           pgfortran  -L. caller.o -lcalled  -o $@
caller.o: caller.f90
           pgfortran  -c caller.f90
libcalled.so: called.f90
           ifort  -shared -fPIC $^ -o $@
```

Notice the "`cl%a(1:10)`" here, witout the "`(1:10)`" there would be nothing printed.

This code finally printed out the elements in the `cl(1)%a` and then hit a segmentation fault in the next line where I tried to print out the array `cl(1)%b`.

If I change the "`cl%a(1:10)`" to "cl%a(1:100)", and delete the "`print *, cl%b(1:10)`". It would give a result of:

[image: results]

We can find that the elements in the b array are there but I just can not fetch them by the "`cl%b(1:10)`".

I know that this may be caused by the different derived type structure of different compilers. But I really want a way by which we can pass this kind of derived type between compilers. Any solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ABI of the compilers can differ. You should not pass the structures directly, but build them inside the subroutines and use pointers, which you should pass as `type(c_ptr)` or as assumed size arrays (but a copy can happen then!).

The interoperability with C from Fortran 2003 is not meant only to interact with C but any other compiler interoperable with C. It can be a diferent Fortran compiler.

Be aware it is against the rules of Fortran to declare the same type in more places and use it as the same type, unless the type is `sequence` or `bind(C)`. This is another reason why your program is not standard conforming.

called.f90:

```
subroutine  offload(cl_c)                                                                  
use iso_c_binding

type, bind(C) :: cell_C                                                                               
integer :: id                                                                            
integer :: na, nb, nc
type(c_ptr)  :: a,b,c                                                                                                                             
end type cell_C

type cell                                                                               
integer :: id
real, pointer :: a(:)                                                                
real, pointer :: b(:)                                                                
real, pointer :: c(:)                                                                
end type cell

type(cell) :: cl
type(cell_C) :: cl_C
integer :: n

cl%id = cl_C%id
call c_f_pointer(cl_C%a, cl%a, [cl_c%na])
call c_f_pointer(cl_C%b, cl%b, [cl_c%nb])
call c_f_pointer(cl_C%c, cl%c, [cl_c%nc])

print *, cl%a(1:10)
print *, cl%b(1:10)   
end subroutine offload
```

caller.f90:

```
program caller
use iso_c_binding

type, bind(C) :: cell_C                                                                               
integer :: id                                                                            
integer :: na, nb, nc
type(c_ptr)  :: a,b,c                                                                                                                             
end type cell_C

type cell                                                                                
integer :: id                                                                            
real, allocatable :: a(:)                                                                
real, allocatable :: b(:)                                                                
real, allocatable :: c(:)                                                                
end type cell                                                                            

integer :: n,i,j

type(cell),target :: cl(2)
type(cell_c) :: cl_c
 n=10                                                                                    
do i=1,2                                                                                 
allocate(cl(i)%a(n))                                                                     
allocate(cl(i)%b(n))                                                                     
allocate(cl(i)%c(n))                                                                     
end do                                                                                   

do j=1, 2                                                                                
do i=1, n                                                                                
cl(j)%a(i)=10*j+i                                                                        
cl(j)%b(i)=10*i+j                                                                        
end do                                                                                   
end do                                                                                   

cl_c%a = c_loc(cl(1)%a)
cl_c%b = c_loc(cl(1)%b)
cl_c%c = c_loc(cl(1)%c)
cl_c%na =  size(cl(1)%a)
cl_c%nb =  size(cl(1)%b)
cl_c%nc =  size(cl(1)%c)
cl_c%id =  cl(1)%id

call offload(cl_c)                                                                      
print *, cl(1)%c  
end program caller
```

with gfortran and ifort:

```
>gfortran  called.f90 -c -o called.o
>ifort  caller.f90 -c -o caller.o
>ifort -o a.out called.o caller.o -lgfortran
>./a.out
11.0000000       12.0000000       13.0000000       14.0000000       15.0000000       16.0000000       17.0000000       18.0000000       19.0000000       20.0000000    
   11.0000000       21.0000000       31.0000000       41.0000000       51.0000000       61.0000000       71.0000000       81.0000000       91.0000000       101.000000    
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
```

No dynamic libraries necessary here.

For 100% theoretical portability one could use `c_int`, `c_float`,... the formatting could be better and so on, but you get the point.

You can also overload the assignments between `cell` and `cell_C` to ease the conversion.

Comment: can the a(:),b(:),c(:) in cell in called.f90 be allocatable arrays? I tried it, it will give a double free or corruption error. I kind of need one of them be allocatable array in order to to a paticular offload

Comment: No, they cannot be. Allocatable can be only something in the memory allocated by the particular compiler. If it was allocated by a different compiler, it must be pointed to by a pointer.

Comment: However, I do not understand I you managed to compile it with allocatables at all, if you used suggestion from my answer, it shouldn't be possible. I do not understand why you would need it. If you really really need them, you just have to copy the values there from the pointer arrays.

Comment: Because I'm trying to use one Xeon Phi offload directive which can offload one array on the host to another array with different name on the Xeon Phi. For example if I have array A and B on the host both have size of m and we have an allocatable array C which has size of 2m , I can offload the A to the first half of C on the Phi and B to the second half of C on the Phi. But if we define a pointer which points to C and use it as part of the offload directive, then there will be something wrong. So that's why I don't want a pointer.

Comment: And I don't need what within the C array, I just need the name of C array, Intel map host and device array by name. But a pointer of an array will cause some issue to the offload directive.

Comment: This is strange, even very strange, but we cannot solve it here. It is a separate issue, if you want, start a new question.